# EF Core 7: How to find top-level parent of an EntityEntry derived from ChangeTracker

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Using EF Core 7, I am implementing an Audit log solution for the top-level parent (aggregate root) entity. I have a list of EntityEntry that the ChangeTracker provided me.

**Question**: Is there a way to determine for each EntityEntry if it is a top-level parent entity? If it is a child, then determine which Entity is the top-level parent?

```
var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(q => q.State == EntityState.Modified || q.State == EntityState.Deleted || q.State == EntityState.Added);
```

Is there a built-in function that can return the top-level parent?

Otherwise, my only thought is to recursively use the Navigations to find it.

```
// Recursive function to get the top-level parent entity
public object GetTopLevelParent(EntityEntry entry)
{
    // Check if the current entry is the top-level parent entity
    if (entry.Metadata.ToClrType == typeof(TopLevelParent))
    {
        return entry.Entity;
    }

    // Traverse the navigation properties to get the top-level parent entity
    foreach (var navigationEntry in entry.Navigations)
    {
        var navigationValue = navigationEntry.CurrentValue;

        if (navigationValue != null)
        {
            var navigationEntry = dbContext.Entry(navigationValue);
            var topLevelParent = GetTopLevelParent(navigationEntry);

            if (topLevelParent != null)
            {
                return topLevelParent;
            }
        }
    }

    // Top-level parent entity not found
    return null;
}
```

**Side Note**: I've done extensive research, with no luck, trying to find an Auditing solution that will create a single Audit record in the DB for the top-level parent. The audit record will contain a JSON data field that should contain all changes made at the parent as well as the children. This will exponentially minimize the number of rows created in the Audit table.

Comment: Have you got a solution ? I search exactly the same thing

Comment: @JeePakaJP turns out this is a very loaded question. How does one determine what qualifies as a top-level parent? In my situation, if I traversed the Navigations (foreign-key relations) it would indeed take me to my parent, but then my parent had a parent as well. I could have in theory define a list of "top-level parents" and then during traversal check the current level to see if it equals the "top-level parent", but that solution did not feel right. So instead, our solution to obtain the full object graph was to start from the parent and get all his children.